# Need for speed: Slow nested groupbys and applys in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am performing a complex transformation on a DataFrame. I thought it would be quick for Pandas, but the only way I've managed to do it is with some nested groupbys and applys, using lambda functions, and it is slow. It seems like the sort of thing where there should be built-in, faster methods. At n_rows=1000 it's 2 seconds, but I'll be doing 10^7 rows, so this is far too slow. It's difficult to explain what we're doing, so here's the code and profile, then I'll explain:

```
n_rows = 1000

d = pd.DataFrame(randint(1,10,(n_rows,8))) #Raw data
dgs = array([3,4,1,8,9,2,3,7,10,8]) #Values we will look up, referenced by index
grps = pd.cut(randint(1,5,n_rows),arange(1,5)) #Grouping

f = lambda x: dgs[x.index].mean() #Works on a grouped Series
g = lambda x: x.groupby(x).apply(f) #Works on a Series
h = lambda x: x.apply(g,axis=1).mean(axis=0) #Works on a grouped DataFrame

q = d.groupby(grps).apply(h) #Slow



824984 function calls (816675 primitive calls) in 1.850 seconds
Ordered by: internal time
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
221770    0.105    0.000    0.105    0.000 {isinstance}
  7329    0.104    0.000    0.217    0.000 index.py:86(__new__)
  8309    0.089    0.000    0.423    0.000 series.py:430(__new__)
  5375    0.081    0.000    0.081    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
 34225    0.068    0.000    0.133    0.000 {method 'view' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
36780/36779    0.067    0.000    0.067    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.array}
  5349    0.065    0.000    0.567    0.000 series.py:709(_get_values)
 985/1    0.063    0.000    1.847    1.847 groupby.py:608(apply)
  5349    0.056    0.000    0.198    0.000 _methods.py:42(_mean)
  5358    0.050    0.000    0.232    0.000 index.py:332(__getitem__)
  8309    0.049    0.000    0.228    0.000 series.py:3299(_sanitize_array)
  9296    0.047    0.000    0.116    0.000 index.py:1341(__new__)
   984    0.039    0.000    0.092    0.000 algorithms.py:105(factorize)
```

Group the DataFrame rows by the groupings. For each grouping, for each row, group by those values that are the same (i.e. all have the value 3 versus all have value 4). For each index in a value grouping, look up the corresponding index in `dgs`, and average. Then average for the row groupings.

::exhale::

Any suggestions on how to rearrange this for speed would be appreciated.

Comment: doing a nested a nested apply/grouping like this is not the answer. This is almost pure python code, you are not leveraging any of pandas strengths. You prob want to groupby at the top level (or construct a multi-index), select the values that you want to include, then use a cythonized function to apply it. You only want to do 1 level of groupby and apply (except in some very very rare cases). You are ultimately are doing some vectorized operations, but you are doing them backwards at the lowest level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the apply and groupby by one multilevel groupby, here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import array, arange
from numpy.random import randint, seed

seed(42)
n_rows = 1000

d = pd.DataFrame(randint(1,10,(n_rows,8))) #Raw data
dgs = array([3,4,1,8,9,2,3,7,10,8]) #Values we will look up, referenced by index
grps = pd.cut(randint(1,5,n_rows),arange(1,5)) #Grouping

f = lambda x: dgs[x.index].mean() #Works on a grouped Series
g = lambda x: x.groupby(x).apply(f) #Works on a Series
h = lambda x: x.apply(g,axis=1).mean(axis=0) #Works on a grouped DataFrame

print d.groupby(grps).apply(h) #Slow

### my code starts from here ###

def group_process(df2):
    s = df2.stack()
    v = np.repeat(dgs[None, :df2.shape[1]], df2.shape[0], axis=0).ravel()
    return pd.Series(v).groupby([s.index.get_level_values(0), s.values]).mean().mean(level=1)

print d.groupby(grps).apply(group_process)
```

output:

```
               1         2         3         4         5         6         7  \
(1, 2]  4.621575  4.625887  4.775235  4.954321  4.566441  4.568111  4.835664   
(2, 3]  4.446347  4.138528  4.862613  4.800538  4.582721  4.595890  4.794183   
(3, 4]  4.776144  4.510119  4.391729  4.392262  4.930556  4.695776  4.630068   

               8         9  
(1, 2]  4.246085  4.520384  
(2, 3]  5.237360  4.418934  
(3, 4]  4.829167  4.681548  

[3 rows x 9 columns]
               1         2         3         4         5         6         7  \
(1, 2]  4.621575  4.625887  4.775235  4.954321  4.566441  4.568111  4.835664   
(2, 3]  4.446347  4.138528  4.862613  4.800538  4.582721  4.595890  4.794183   
(3, 4]  4.776144  4.510119  4.391729  4.392262  4.930556  4.695776  4.630068   

               8         9  
(1, 2]  4.246085  4.520384  
(2, 3]  5.237360  4.418934  
(3, 4]  4.829167  4.681548  

[3 rows x 9 columns]
```

It's about 70x faster, but I don't know if it can work with 10**7 rows.

Comment: FYI this is a completely parallelizable problem once u split the groups and you could say do them in separate processes, eg something like concat(dict([ (g,group_process2(grp)) for g, grp in d.groupby(grps) ]))